# How can i get json value

Tags: jquery

my json

```
var json = {"data":[{"DT_RowId":"row_25","sip":{"fall":"0","whoa":"1"}}],"options":[],"files":[]}
```

I want get fall value and whoa value ?

I'm trying like this but not working.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj.sip.fall);
```

Comment: Is your JSON supposed to be a string ? This is no valid JSON.

Comment: You could've easliy seen what's wrong if tried looking at the output of `console.log(obj);` before posting here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to skip a couple steps. You need to navigate the 'path' of the object more accurately, it should be apparent from this demonstration.

```js
var json = '{ "data":[ { "DT_RowId":"row_25", "sip":{ "fall":"0", "whoa":"1" } } ], "options":[], "files":[]}'

var obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj);

console.log(obj.data);

console.log(obj.data[0]);

console.log(obj.data[0].sip);

console.log(obj.data[0].sip.fall);
```